# Push structured string with variables in JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I am trying to push a specific string with variables in a JS array.

My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = "{$p.id}"+"-"+"{$p.id_val}";
    var price = "{$p.price}";
    var category = "{$p.category}";

    var full_line = "{ id: "+id+", price: "+price+", category: "+category+"},";

    console.log(full_line);
    myArray.push(full_line);
</script>
```

It works fine but it does not work if within the full line I have these symbols: { }
Below you can see the line without those symbols, if I leave it like that it works fine.

```
var full_line = "id: "+id+", price: "+price+", category: "+category;
```

But I need those symbols because I have to pass the exact same structure in a js tracking code. If the symbols { } are included, the page is broken. Is there any way or 'trick' in order to include them in an array element and push them?

Comment: Treat it as objects and then stringify using `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: What is the point of this anyways? Do you think `"{$p.id}"` is supposed to evaluate to something?

Comment: I will try the json stringify, thanks. "{$p.id}" will return a number yes. And I just need to pass that line in a tracking code. I cannot change anything in the structure

Comment: `JSON.stringify({ id: id, price: price, category: category })`

Comment: What do you think this is PHP? It's not going to evaluate to anything unless you make it. That's just a JavaScript String.

Comment: It is working fine, I just didn't post the whole code. That is not the problem there. I am just trying to pass a specific string in an array. Other than that, the rest works fine

Comment: You would need some lower case quotes `"id: '"+id+"'` and the like, or when it gets evaluated, it will see those as bad Objects.

Comment: thank you, I will try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot "push" into an object you can do it easily like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = "{$p.id}"+"-"+"{$p.id_val}";
    var price = "{$p.price}";
    var category = "{$p.category}";

    var full_line = {};
    full_line.id = id;
    full_line.price = price;
    full_line.category = category;

    console.log(full_line);
    myArray.push(full_line);
</script>
```

OR

If you need it as as a string you can treat it as an object as I saw you and then convert it to string by doing: `JSON.stringify(full_line)`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I am going to test it

Comment: It kind of works but not exactly... It prints this (just an example) --> {"id":"200","price":"15","category":"one"} <-- Not sure why the quotes are there. It should be like that --> {id:200, price:15, category:one}, <-- with the comma in the end as well and no quotes. Sorry if I ask for too much, it just the first time I use this JSON array

Comment: It does that on id and price because this is how you define them. For example you say `var price = "{$p.price}"` (you put the quotes there). Change that to `var price = {$p.price};`. That can be truth on id and price i those are integers but it cannot stand for a string (category). etc.

Comment: That is true yes, but i can also see quotes within the name 'price' or 'id' etc... is there any way i can eliminate the quotes and also add a comma value in the end? (I will change the category and pass number, it's ok). If you now any tutorial or anything related, I would be glad to read it. Thanks

Comment: I gave you a solution in my previous comment. Also if the answer solved your problem that your question describe please accept it. You cannot add a comma after the object is closed. I think your requirements are strange if not wrong.

Comment: Hello, you answer helped a lot and I will accept it :) One last thing, what I meant in my previous question is that the quotes are also in the price.If I have this var price = {$p.price}; then it will print the number just fine. But the name 'price' will be in quotes. Isn't it possible to stringify the whole line, even the names 'id', 'price', 'category' and not only their values? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: That's how you get them by default. When you parse them (request them etc) this doesn't make any difference though. I'm guessing that after you stringify the object you can find the quotes and remove them. You'll find looots of answers in SO for that matter ;)

Comment: You too and keep it up ;)